# iOS "PodCast" app fils up my phone; doesn't pre-download podcasts I want

Tags: podcasts.app

I've started using Apple's Podcast app and I've encountered some unexplainable behavior.

- I have it configured to download podcasts and only keep the last 5 unplayed.
- Nevertheless, it periodically downloads months and months of Podcasts that I haven't heard. In the process, it fills up my iPhone.
- However, it's frequently the case that it hasn't downloaded the most recent podcast. This is really annoying to me, because I'm using the Podcast app when I'm underground, in the subway, and there's no Internet access.

Is there any solution to this? Have other people seen the problem?

Comment: May I suggest [Overcast](https://overcast.fm)?

Comment: I will investigate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to a particular podcast settings, the options available are better described, and may explain the behavior you are seeing:

The option "Limit episodes" has a description that reads:

> Limit the number of new episodes shown in the Unplayed view

[image: podcast settings, limit episodes]

Which does not appear to define how many episodes are downloaded but only how they are displayed.

This description is not present if you go to the app settings on the iOS Settings app.

On a separate setting you can choose to only download new episodes, all episodes or all unplayed. My guess is that marking "Only new" will help with your issue, but it depends on what is considered new by the app of course.